# Determining the optimal DB pool size for Rails 4 app on Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku, puma

I've been having trouble with `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError` errors on my app lately. It's a Rails 4 app deployed to Heroku on Puma. When I run `heroku pg:info` I can see that only 5/20 connections are active when I encounter the `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError` error. I ended up increasing my `MAX_THREADS` and `MIN_THREADS` env variable from 2 to 5 after reading [this forum post on Heroku](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/heroku-database-connection-time-out-error/737/4), which made the problem disappear for now, but that solution seems like applying some black magic to the problem and hoping it goes away.

What I would like to know is how I can properly determine how big my connection pool needs to be. Right now I have a single web worker and two additional `resque` workers running.

My app currently handles a lot of S3 image uploads, which I think may be triggering the problem. This is something I'm thinking of passing off to a `resque` worker to free up the web worker. I did notice that the upload process sped up dramatically after I upped the pool size, however I'm concerned that just uping the pool size is not a scalable long-term solution.